# How to execute a workflow on a PC which doesn't have the UiPath Studio or UiPath Robot installed?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot

How to execute a workflow on a PC which doesn't have the *UiPath Studio* or *UiPath Robot* installed?

I have been working with UiPath to automate workflows using *UiPath Studio* and *UiPath Robot* (both locally and on localhost through Orchestrator) and was successful.

I have been through the following videos from `academy.uipath` :

- *Lesson Orchestrator 2018.2 - Video Part 1*
- *Lesson Orchestrator 2018.2 - Video Part 2*

I am aware I need to:

- Add a host as a *Standard Machine* first
- Then add a *Standard Robot*
- Further provision the *Robot* within the *Orchestrator* settings.

Now I want to execute a workflow on a bare PC which doesn't have either the *UiPath Studio* or *UiPath Robot* installed.

So my questions are:

- (Q1): Is an installation of *UiPath Studio* and/or *UiPath Robot* the bare minimum requirement to execute a workflow through a UiPath Robot, guided through the *UiPath Orchestrator*?
- *Windows Installation* can be done through:

  - `UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe`
  - `UiPathStudio.msi`
- (Q2): Can I install *UiPath Robot* **only** (excluding the UiPath Studio) using either of the installers?

I had used the `UiPathStudioSetup` *Application* which installs both *UiPath Studio* and *UiPath Robot* by default. So:

- (Q3): Would `UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe` allow me to install the *UiPath Robot* individually?
- (Q4): Would a Robot installed through `UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe` communicate with *Orchestrator CE*

**Note**: As per [Free Trial or Community Edition UiPath RPA Software](https://www.uipath.com/freetrial-or-community) my understanding is:

- `UiPathStudio.msi` is for *The UiPath Community Edition*
- `UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe` is for *The UiPath Enterprise RPA Platform*
- (Q5): Am I correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hello i will try to answers your questions as follow:

**(Q1):** Is an installation of UiPath Studio and/or UiPath Robot the bare minimum requirement to execute a workflow through a UiPath Robot, guided through the UiPath Orchestrator?

**(A1)**: The minimum requirements are:

1. UiPath Studio along with preinstalled UiPath Robot (UiPathStudio.msi)
2. Orchestrator with UiPath Robot separately installed (UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe) (Manage, schedule, monitor multiple robots/environments and importantly using Queues)
3. UiPath Robot (Just execute existing workflows, check their logs).

   Which brings us to your second question.

**(Q2):** Can I install UiPath Robot only (excluding the UiPath Studio) using either of the installers?

**(A2):** Yes you can install only the Robot without the studio, if you run the setup file as administrator and perform a custom setup. as per screen below:
[image]

**(Q3):** Would UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe allow me to install the UiPath Robot individually?

**(A3):** Yes as per (Q2) the only difference is that this installer comes along with Orchestrator, which you can choose to skip in custom installation.

**(Q4):** Would a Robot installed through UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe communicate with Orchestrator CE

**(A4):** Yes if you provision the Robot to the respected Orchestrator

Note: As per Free Trial or Community Edition UiPath RPA Software my understanding is:

```
UiPathStudio.msi is for The UiPath Community Edition
UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe is for The UiPath Enterprise RPA Platform
```

**(Q5):** Am I correct?

**(A5):** Yes you are. You can request the Community Edition if you are an individual or small company or the Enterprise Trial if you are an enterprise.
Fill out one of the forms here and you will get the installer via email:[UiPathFreeTrialOrCommunity](https://www.uipath.com/freetrial-or-community)

Answer (score 3):

> (Q1): Is an installation of UiPath Studio and/or UiPath Robot the bare
>   minimum requirement to execute a workflow through a UiPath Robot,
>   guided through the UiPath Orchestrator?

As per [About Installation](https://studio.uipath.com/docs/about-installation), the only difference between `UiPathStudio.msi` and `UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe` is that the latter one can be used to install Orchestrator. Besides from that, they are identical - and installing Studio is purely optional (yet enabled by default, must be cleared in the advanced options).

> (Q2): Can I install UiPath Robot only (excluding the UiPath Studio)
>   using either of the installers?
>
> (Q3): Would UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe allow me to install the UiPath
>   Robot individually?

Yes, via an advanced installation. You may also want to check out all available [Command Line Arguments](https://studio.uipath.com/docs/msi-command-line-parameters).

> (Q4): Would a Robot installed through UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe
>   communicate with Orchestrator CE

Yes, I don't see why that shouldn't be possible. Never tried it, though.

> (Q5): Am I correct?

Since there is (at least to my knowledge) no official way to obtain `UiPathPlatformInstaller.exe` without a license, `UiPathStudio.msi` is the way to go. However, as noted above, technically speaking there is difference between the two with the exception being Orchestrator.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to launch a UiPath Robot without the UiPath Robot software being installed on the machine which will to execute the automation. A "bare" machine will not be able to execute any automation created by UiPath. There are different levels of licensing, all of which revolve around 4 products. In order of least to most expensive, those products are an attended robot, UiPath Studio, an unattended robot, and UiPath Orchestrator. UiPath Studio includes an attended robot as this is the mechanism which allows for the execution on a user desktop.

To launch an automation from Orchestrator, at minimum an unattended robot must be purchased and installed on the machine which must execute the bot. There is some grey area in terms of what constitutes a machine, there are ways to provision unattended robots to virtual machines, but each automation launched from Orchestrator must be run on a valid unattended robot license.

Attended robots are not able to be launched from Orchestrator. They must be launched from the machine which will execute the automation. This is how the software is monetized. This is not like C, where any (windows) computer already has the necessary components to compile and execute the instructions.

You are correct that there are separate installers for Community and Enterprise interpretations though.