# Install UiPath Robot ony multiple machines via commandline to have a fast deployment without configuration needed

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

[How to execute a workflow on a PC which doesn't have the UiPath Studio or UiPath Robot installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244174/how-to-execute-a-workflow-on-a-pc-which-doesnt-have-the-uipath-studio-or-uipath) inspired me to install Robot on my 2nd machine.

I would like to install the Robot on that machine. So I wanted to install the Robot silently and connect it to Orchestrator automatically:

> UiPathStudio.msi ADDLOCAL=DesktopFeature,Robot,RegisterService
>   CONNECTIONSTRING=https://platform.uipath.com?tenantId=SERVICENAME
>   /Q

But what is my personal connectionstring and the tenantId? I was looking for info in my account. But there is no URL neither an ID. How to get them now?

See also:

- [connectionstring generation](https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-get-the-connectionstring-tenantid-for-automated-installation-process/155238)
- [project version makes problems](https://forum.uipath.com/t/getting-error-detecting-project-version-when-project-is-run-on-machine-with-a-minimal-uipath-robot-installation/155946)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to install a robot is to install a Studio.

You can find your tenantName in the orchestrator URL after you login (https://platform.uipath.com/YourTenantname/portal_/serviceinstances)

you can find your tenantID as you go to:
Orchestrator>>services>>click your tenantname>> you will go to your account, look at the URL (https://platform.uipath.com/tenantName /tenantName /?ou=XXXXX&tid=**YYYYYY**) your tenantID have to be there

Comment: Sure that's clear. But that's overkill. That machine does not need the Studio. Why should I install software that is not needed. But thanks anyway. If I find not a better way I might think this one here.

Answer (score 1):

You can run **robots** without **Orch** connected but to run Robot in a certain machine you need to provision this machine unless you install UiRobot without the studio or you can get a **front office** license and trigger the bot from there it using *.bat file or you can trigger by **scheduling** through windows task scheduler.

Please mark as answered if this help :)

Comment: This sounds very interesting to me! But could you go a bit more into detail with a step-by-step? That would help me a lot. So you said I should use a bat file. You mean install with `UiPathStudio.msi ADDLOCAL=DesktopFeature,Robot,RegisterService` and then run the bat file with `robot.exe ...`? And for sure the machine need to be provisioned. That's clear.